# How can I get template body [text] in apex class?

Tags: apex, email-template, singleemailmessage

Here is my code below:

```
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> allmsg = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    EmailTemplate ti = [Select id,Subject,Body from EmailTemplate where name = 'email template on customer'];
    for(Customer__c cus:lst1){
        mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();                
        mail.setTemplateId(ti.Id);
        mail.setToAddresses(new String[]{cus.Email__c});
        mail.setSubject(ti.Subject);
        mail.setPlainTextBody(ti.Body);
        allmsg.add(mail);
    }
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason to do so? If you create the SingleEmailMessage with a template ID then the template itself is automatically retrieved - you do not need to provide Subject and body values.

Comment: BTW, if you look at the [Message methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_email_outbound_messaging.htm) you will see you can get rendered email details if you want.